# When do I exactly need a pointer with structs

Tags: c, pointers

I really do not understand if and when do I need to declare a pointer to my data struct.

I have two programs and both works the same, but I cant figure out where should I need a pointer or not.

Here are the programs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct data
{
    char *ptr;
};

void printStruct( struct data pers );

int main (void)
{
    struct data pers;   // Here pers is not a POINTER

    pers.ptr = malloc(sizeof (char) * 256);
    strcpy(pers.ptr, "Hello World");

    printStruct(pers);
    free(pers.ptr);
}

void printStruct( struct data pers ){
    printf("PTR = %s\n", pers.ptr);
}
```

When do I exactly need a pointer?

As you can see, here `struct data pers;` I declared a variable and in the next example I am using a pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct data
{
    char *ptr;
};

void printStruct( struct data *pers );

void printStruct( struct data *pers ){
    printf("PTR = %s\n", pers->ptr);
}

int main (void)
{
    struct data *pers;   // Here pers is a POINTER
    pers = malloc(sizeof(*pers));
    pers->ptr = malloc(sizeof (char) * 256);
    strcpy(pers->ptr, "Hello World");

    printStruct(pers);

    free(pers->ptr);
    free(pers);
}
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: You don't need a pointer until you need a pointer. If you can fulfil the goal without using a pointer don't use it. The same applies to every concept, especially those you don't master yet.

Comment: I'm not asking when and where should I use a Pointer, but in this case using a struct variable I really not know where is a Pointer needed. Could you please provide me an Example where a Pointer is needed.

Comment: Sometime there are several ways to implement a solution to the same use case.

Comment: A pointer is needed whenever you don't know the address of an object at compile time. For example when allocating memory dynamically (because it could be anywhere), when passing objects "by reference" (because the function can be called with different objects), when scanning an array (because the next item is computed by the program). In general, if you keep programming in C (avoiding pointers at first) you'll soon reach the point when you'll *feel* the need for a pointer. Hence my previous advice. So keep on programming :)

Comment: As a general rule, you want to avoid copying structures, unless you truly need to copy them.  So rather than passing a structure as a function argument, it is better to pass a pointer to it, avoiding the need to copy the entire structure.  It is rare that you need to pass the structure itself as a function argument.

Comment: Use them when your brain says that you need them. There is no general rule, mega rule or Ten Commandments of pointer use :)

Comment: Pointers are essential for building complex data structures such as linked lists and binary trees. Also they are required by functions to be able to modify variables outside their scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four cases where you *have* to use a pointer to a `struct`:

1. You want a function to write to a parameter of `struct` type:

   ```
   struct foo { int member; }

   void updateFoo( struct foo *bar )
   {
     bar->member = some_new_value();
   }

   int main( void )
   {
     struct foo f = {0};
     ...
     updateFoo( &f );
   }
   ```

   You want to allocate one or more instances of a `struct` type dynamically:

   ```
   struct foo *farr = malloc( sizeof *farr * NUM_ELEMENTS );
   ```

   You're using a `struct` type with a flexible array member:

   ```
   struct foo { int x; char y[]; }

   struct foo *instance = malloc( sizeof *instance + LENGTH_FOR_Y_MEMBER );
   ```

   You want to define a self-referential type (i.e., each instance of `struct foo` points to a different instance of `struct foo`:

   ```
   struct list_node { int data; struct list_node *next; }
   ```

   This is a common implementation of a singly-linked list - each element of the list explicitly points to the next element in the list (or `NULL` if at the last element).

You may also choose to pass a pointer to a `struct` to a function, even if the function doesn't modify the parameter, just to save the overhead of creating a copy in the called function, especially if the `struct` type is large:

```
struct ginormous { /* define many large members here */ };

void blah( const struct ginormous *g )
{
  // do stuff with g
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular benefit in case `3` to allocating the entire struct in that manner, as opposed to allocating for `sizeof (*instance)` and then another allocation for `char y[]`? My linter screams at me when I try that approach.

Comment: @DevNull: TBH, I've never used flexible array members in my own code.  I think the chief benefit is making serialization easier; you can `memcpy` the whole instance at once, rather than copying part of it, chasing down the pointer, and then copying the rest.